# _HasValidUrlName not working

Tags: sxa

I have inherited my items from `_HasValidUrlName template`, that should create valid item name. for example replace spaces to dash. but item display name would be equal to user input.

but at `Sitecore 9` it is not working by some reason, at `Sitecore 8` it was ok.

does anyone know why ?

Comment: Could you provide more information on this? How does the functionality of ensuring the item name is valid work?

Comment: @Kasaku for example when user create item with spaces like "My Page" item name would be my-page, but display name would be "My Page"

Comment: _HasValidUrlName sounds like a custom template? Can you elaborate how this enforced a valid name in you Sitecore 8 solution?

Comment: @BryanArcher It's related to SXA, something ootb using that module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that this part was move out from SXA configs settings

```
 <events>
          <event name="item:added">
            <handler patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Data.Fields.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation.EventHandlers.SeoUrlHelper, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation" method="OnItemAdded"/>
          </event>
          <event name="item:renamed">
            <handler type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation.EventHandlers.SeoUrlHelper, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation" method="OnItemRenamed"/>
          </event>
          <event name="item:copied">
            <handler patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation.EventHandlers.SeoUrlHelper, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation" method="OnItemCopied"/>
          </event>
        </events>
```

Answer (score 2):

Which version of SXA are you using?

Based on what I have come across, `_HasValidUrlName` is used in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation` to check if the item being created is inherited from `_HasValidUrlName` template but it doesn't check for what you are looking for atleast in `Sitecore SXA 1.8`

```
public struct _SeoUrlValid
{
  public static ID ID = ID.Parse("{0A7DA0A0-FCD9-4B7B-A725-E159FA3E7E6C}");
}

protected virtual bool ShouldValidate(Item item)
{
  return item.DoesItemInheritFrom(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation.Templates._SeoUrlValid.ID);
}
```

You can start from there and dig further. Hope it helps!

Comment: sitecore 9.2 and sxa 1.9

Answer (score 0):

We came across this issue where the item names are no longer renamed to lowercase with dashes (which includes the updated Display Name). After stumbling across this post I thought I would add a few comments.

1. Some time after `Sitecore 8.2.7` the class `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.ContentValidation.EventHandlers.SeoUrlHelper` was removed and the associated event config as noted by @Arbejdsglæde. I'm guessing `Sitecore 9.0 or 9.1`.
2. When we transitioned to `Sitecore 9.3` we did not notice this behavior change. The URLs still generate on the live site with dashes so no one complained.
3. We have a custom `LinkProvider` to lowercase URLs and a custom `ItemProvider` to ensure the trailing forward slash.